# How to pass arguments from one function to other functions?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, function, parameters, arguments

I have created three functions. The first function is used in the other two functions but I am passing it a hardcoded filepath. I want to be able to pass this in as a parameter, but I seem to be getting an issue.
Essentially, given a file_path, my function will get the first item in the list and then the second item.

So far my code is as follows :

```
def sort_files(file_path):
    """Sort files in ascending order"""
    files = os.listdir(file_path)
    return sorted(files, reverse=True)


def current_day():
    """Get the current day file"""
    return sort_files(file_path)[0]


def previous_day():
    """Get the previous day file"""
    return sort_files(file_path)[1]
```

Comment: Please explain the nature of the "issue" you are getting.

Comment: why not make `file_path` a parameter in your functions

Comment: @ScottHunter

Well when i am passing file_path within my function current_day and previous_day , i get an error saying "unresolved reference 'path'"

Comment: @Primusa

Could you provide an example

Comment: Because `file_path` isn't defined in those functions; you have to pass it *to* them from the caller(s).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function to accept an argument, you need to define it as doing so by specifying the parameter name it will be known as in the function (as you did with `sort_files`).

Answer (score 0):

How are you executing the call to the current_day and previous_day. You should make them as function that can take a parameter.

Also please post the code that you are using to execute the whole setup.